"Show single Polygon" Atlas Filter Expression
What can a filter expression be that only displays the areas of a coverage flyer that have a unique ID in the atlas function of QGIS and not all areas of a selected column?
The aim is to generate automated site plans that only show one specific property at a time.
Is it possible by maybe using a specific rule based layer-styling to also see the features in my map view?
For example that one rule excludes the other depending on which view you are in, printer layout or map view.

Thank you! However, I would like to see all features in the map view at all times. Using the above expression, the map view only shows me the areas that I have selected in the atlas or in the print layout. The control then also works via the print layout. Is there a way to do so

you can use a ruled based layer-styling with the following rule:
$id = @atlas_featureid 

which will show in the atlas only the current atlas feature, all others will be invisible. Be aware that in your map view the features will also disapear, until you activate preview of the atlas


If you want to use some other field rather than fid you can use this code: "some_layer_field_name" = attribute(@atlas_feature, 'atlas_field_name')

You can get around the items disappearing in your main canvas view by adding this to the filter expression: AND @map_id != 'canvas'
